# How do I specify that a component within an OpenCPI application xml is within an HDL assembly?

Tags: c, fpga

> Components within an OpenCPI application need to be specified such that their location is identified. My xml is below. The file_read and file_write seem to be found ok but ocpirun reports that no acceptable implementation can be found for the other components. They are within an HDL assembly/container.
>
> I have tried many variations along the lines of local."component", local."binary file name"."component" and many others.

```
<Application done='file_write'>
    <Instance component='ocpi.core.file_read' name='file_read' connect='fft_1024'>
        <property name='filename' value='react_jammer_rx.input'/>
        <property name='granularity' value='4'/>
        <property name='messageSize' value='1024'/>
    </Instance>
    <Instance component='fft_1024_xs' name='fft_1024' connect='peak_detector'/>
    <Instance component='peak_detector_xs_us' name='peak_detector' connect='file_write'/>
    <Instance component='ocpi.core.file_write' name='file_write'>
        <property name='filename' value='react_jammer_rx.output'/>
    </Instance>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the project package-ID to the start of your `fft_1024_xs` and `peak_detector_xs_us` components. If you have registered your project (using `ocpidev register project` in your project root directory) you can find this out using `ocpidev show registry` and it will appear in the list.

Comment: Alternatively, they should be in the `Project.xml` file at the top level of your project. If not specified they tend to take the form `local.<project_folder_name>`

Comment: Thanks. The fix for me was that the component name needed to be preceded by local."project name".